# How to get IP address with a host name?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am making a  client that connect to a server that is locally hosted that gets stock numbers from the server. The program does work if i use this code below but the way it works is by getting the dns name so in theory it only takes www.website.com and I cant figure out how I can get it to recognize a normal ip of 127.0.0.1 or localhost IP:

```
   IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("www.website.com");
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
```

Attached is my attemp to get this to resolve the ip but I dont think I am approaching this right the full code can be seen here:[StockReader Client Code](http://www.cutitclan.com/pasteme/index.php?s)

```
    public class AsynchronousClient
{

    private const int port = 21;

    // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.
    private static ManualResetEvent connectDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);

    // The response from the remote device.
    private static String response = String.Empty;

    private static void StartClient()
    {
        // Connect to a remote device.
        try
        {
            // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
            // The name of the 

      //******************ISSUE BEGINS HERE*********************************  
            string sHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(sHostName);
            IPAddress [] ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList; 
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect to the remote endpoint.
            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();

            // Send test data to the remote device.
            Send(client, "This is a test<EOF>");
            sendDone.WaitOne();

            // Receive the response from the remote device.
            Receive(client);
            receiveDone.WaitOne();

            // Write the response to the console.
            Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);

            // Release the socket.
            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            client.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you set the value of `ipAddress`, you can use the [IPAddress.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse.aspx) method to pass in a string and retrieve an `IPAddress` object instead of using the domain name:

```
string ip = "127.0.0.1";
IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `string sHostName = "localhost";`

Answer (score 0):

```
// Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.  
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, portnumber);

// Create a TCP/IP socket.  
Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
s.Connect(remoteEP);
```